# How to reduce a Boolean Algebra expression/function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I need to reduce this expression:

> $$F(A,B,C,D) = A'B'C'D + A'B'CD + A'BC'D + A'BCD' + AB'C'D + ABC'D' + ABCD'$$

I also have the following solution:

> \begin{align*}
> &= \bar A \bar B D + \bar A \bar B \bar D + A \bar B \bar C D + AB\bar D\\
> &= \bar B D(\bar A + A\bar C) + B \bar D\\
> &= \bar B D(\bar A + \bar C) + B \bar D
> \end{align*}

However, I don't understand it very well, could someone explain me in detail what happened here?

Comment: What are $A',B',C',D',\bar A,\bar B,\bar C,\bar D$? Which part do you not understand? What is switching algebra? What does it have to do with discrete mathematics?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @tomasz http://www.wiley.com/college/engin/balabanian293512/pdf/ch02.pdf

Comment: First of all you have to use [Distributivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) on the part : $A'B'C'D + A'B'CD$ to get : $A'B'D(C+C')=A'B'D$ because $C+C'=1$; and so on ...

Comment: Sorry, not going to read a 47 page PDF to understand your question.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang i didnt ask for you to read it, he asked what is switching math and i gave him a link

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you right,now i get it better :)

Comment: You can see [here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_7/5.html) or [here](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA awesome, thanks buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(A'B'C'D + A'B'CD) + (A'BC'D'+A'BCD') + AB'C'D + (ABC'D' + ABCD')$

$= A'B'D + A'BD' + AB'C'D + ABD'$ (1)

$= (A'B'D + AB'C'D) + (A'BD' + ABD')$ (2)

$= B'D(A'+AC') + BD'$ (3)

$= B'D(A'+C') + BD'$ (4)

(1): You can undistribute in three expressions. The first two terms, for example, can be undistributed as follows: $A'B'D(C'+C) = A'B'D$ since $(C'+C = 1)$. Similarly for the other two pairs.

(2): Just rearranged the terms.

(3): Undistributed both pairs.

(4): $A' +AC' = A'+C'$ because you know that either $A'$ or $A$ is asserted *a priori*. If $A'$ is asserted, you get $1$. If $A$ is asserted instead, well, $AC' = C'$.

Comment: thats great! thanks man :) what is the subject for this matter? I want to upload another question and I think the tags that I gave are incorrect

Comment: You're welcome! And I think "Boolean Algebra" would be the most appropriate tag.

Comment: cool, posted another q if you up for it :P http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153084/how-to-find-a-minimal-expression-of-cnf-and-a-minimal-expressions-of-dnf-for-a-f